# WPF show StackPanel when Checkbox is ticked

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to add a `StackPanel` to my app that is only visible if the user checks a `CheckBox`. The `xaml` I wrote for this is here:

```
<Window>
  <Grid>
    <StackPanel>   
       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox Content="Override Offsets?" Name="offsetCB" Margin="5" Checked="OffsetOverride_Checked" Unchecked="OffsetOverride_Unchecked"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="Collapsed">

            <StackPanel.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=offsetCB, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />

                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Style>

                    <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="Can you see me?"/>
        </StackPanel> 
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
<Window>
```

When the `CheckBox` is checked nothing changes though, I don't see any exceptions or anything like that. The idea is that once this is working I will add more elements that the single `TextBlock`.

I get the feeling that I am probably making a simple mistake, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you directly bind to the Visibility property of the stackpanel? Instead of using DataTriggers.. You might have to use a conveter once you decide to do so

Comment: They're contained inside a `StackPanel` that's inside a `Grid`. I'll edit the Question for clarity. As you can probably tell I'm far from a WPF expert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` that is available in `PresentationFramework`. Declare following resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then you can use the Converter in the XAML code as follows:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <CheckBox Content="Override Offsets?"
              Name="offsetCB" 
              Margin="5"
              Checked="OffsetOverride_Checked" 
              Unchecked="OffsetOverride_Unchecked"/>
</StackPanel>

<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
            Visibility="{Binding Path=IsChecked, 
                         ElementName=offsetCB, 
                         Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll (at least) need to add a `Resource` for the boolean `true` value.  `Value="True"` is a string literal `"True"`, not a boolean.

```
<StackPanel.Resources>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="True">True</s:Boolean>
</StackPanel.Resources>
```

And use it:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=offsetCB, Path=IsChecked}"
             Value="{StaticResource True}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=offsetCB, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=offsetCB, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
```